# How to connect Python with Online Database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm trying to connect Python software with Online Database but it showing me an error.

Note: My real Hostname is Hidden. I've replaced it with 000.000.000.0000

g

```
es\mysql\connector\network.py", line 512, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '000.000.000.000:0000' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: You may have the port number wrong. Or you may be behind a firewall that is blocking the connection.

Comment: is this pot '000.000.000.000:0000' allowed for the connection for the users ?